# Can I delete Mac's DVD Player .enc files?

Tags: macos, dvd

I have a lot of .enc files in this folder:

~/Library/Application Support/DVD Player/Settings

Is it OK to delete these files so that I can free up memory on my Mac? I am presuming that they are files that are created when watching a DVD and it is info that is stored.

Comment: Why not move them to another directory, see if everything works as expected and then delete them?

Comment: I followed the instructions above and copied them to another directory, but onto an external drive, then deleted them from the computer.  Everything seems to be working fine.  I did notice that more are being created when I open a DVD. Now I will delete them from the external drive too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are **enc**rypted files storing information about played DVDs. They are property list files (as stored in previous versions of macOS), and have then been encrypted. They are fine to delete.